# Error deploying Next JS 13 application on GCP App engine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, next.js

Its working fine with Next version 12, but after upgrading to Next 13 its giving me below error.
and current node version: "18.x.x"
Next Js version: "13.2.1"

```
Step #2: /app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:358
Step #2:                     ...pageKeys.app ?? [],
Step #2:                                      ^
Step #2:
Step #2: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
Step #2:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
Step #2:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
Step #2:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
Step #2:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
Step #2:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
Step #2:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
Step #2:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
Step #2:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js:10:37)
Step #2:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
Step #2:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)`
```

I have tried with Node version 16 as well, but not working. Currently I am stuck as its working fine on my local but getting error when I am trying to upload on GCP App Engine.

Comment: The error message indicates that there is a syntax error related to the nullish coalescing operator (??), which was introduced in Node.js version 14. Therefore, it's possible that the Node.js version running on GCP App Engine is not compatible with Next.js 13. You can try modifying your `package.json` file to include `"type": "module"` to enable ECMAScript modules.

Answer (score 1):

How did you select the Node.js version for your app? App Engine will not respect the `engines` setting in your `package.json`. You also need to set the `runtime: nodejs16` in your `app.yaml` file.

Also, typically you will need to add a `gcp-build` script to your `package.json` that runs `next build`.

```
"scripts": {
  "gcp-build": "next build",
}
```

This script will get picked up by the GCP buildpacks when you deploy to GAE and add some addition steps to the build:

1. all your `devDependencies` will be installed
2. `npm run gcp-build` will be executed
3. the `devDependencies` will be pruned from the final app image

Comment: setting runtime: nodejs16 is only supported in standard, I am using flex.
Also for setting the node version I have added below in package.json
    "engines": {
       "node": "18.15.0"
    },